# How do I get Ivy to copy the dependencies to the lib directory when using it from the command line?

Tags: java, command-line, ant, ivy, dependency-management

I have the following command:

```
java -jar ...\ivy-2.2.0-rc1.jar -ivy ...\ivy.xml
```

Which I am expecting to resolve the dependencies and copy them to the lib folder of my project.

Ivy seems to resolve the dependencies but does not do the copy. If I run the  ant task the copy happens correctly.

Does anyone know why the copy to lib does not happen with my command line call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're missing the *retrieve* option.

```
java -jar $IVYJAR \ 
     -settings ivysettings.xml \
     -ivy ivy.xml \
     -retrieve "lib/[artifact].[ext]"
```

You specify a pattern for how the artifact will be retrieved from the cache

By default the standalone ivy program will only resolve a dependency (In other words, only download and cache)